# Custom series connecting line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am plotting graphs for a monitoring system that shows modem signal levels over time.
As the values remain constant over longer periods of time, this system only logs changes.
In short this means: As long as you do not encounter a new data-point, the previous value is active.

In my graph I would like to use connecting lines for a better visualisation. 
Unfortunately the way Highcharts renders this is by simply connecting the points. 
This is wrong as it insinuates the value changed over time.

The only correct way is to show instant changes (90º lines). 
For example: see the red line I (partially) drew in my image. The blue line is what is rendered with the default line type.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

[image: Highcharts plot as it is and how it should be]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use [step](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.line.step) parameter.

Comment: And now I feel stupid for overlooking something as simple as that... You sir, are my hero of the day.